# Gradle dependency caching mechanism

Tags: gradle

Under my user-home/.gradle/caches I am seeing multiple artifacts directories e.g. artifacts-14,artifacts-24, modules-2. 
all these folders are storing duplicate artifacts. so my questions is, why  and in what conditions gradle has to create multiple artifacts folders? can gradle also be configured to lookup and store artifacts in on directory. doing so I can save disk space from storing duplicate artifacts.

Comment: Does each repository cache folder contain the same jars? Or is it just pom/xml files that are duplicated?

Answer (score 2):

highly sophisticated dependency caching, that does not work (3.4). Build file has a new dependency version yet Gradle still fetches artifact from some weird intermediary dependency cache instead of taking the new version from local maven repo

Answer (score 1):

Gradle contains a highly sophisticated dependency caching mechanism.

You can check a first folder `.gradle` located under project directory.
Gradle recreates every time the tasks are run.

Also there is a folder `.gradle` under home directory.
Gradle creates it and uses it to store the depdendencies to reduce the download-time.

**The Gradle dependency cache consists of 2 key types of storage:**

- A file-based store of downloaded artifacts, including binaries like jars as well as raw downloaded meta-data like POM files and Ivy files. The storage path for a downloaded artifact includes the SHA1 checksum, meaning that 2 artifacts with the same name but different content can easily be cached.
- A binary store of resolved module meta-data, including the results of resolving dynamic versions, module descriptors, and artifacts.
  Separating the storage of downloaded artifacts from the cache metadata permits us to do some very powerful things with our cache that would be difficult with a transparent, file-only cache layout.

You can read more [info here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html). Check the `The dependency cache` chapter.